# Why text is not aligned in list items?

Tags: html, css

Given the following simple page, which shows an unordered list:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Day Picker</title>    
    <style>
        *          { margin: 0; }
        html, body { height: 100%; }

        .unordered-list
        {
            height:          100%;
            margin:          0 auto;
            width:           75%;
            text-align:      center;
            list-style-type: none;
        }
        .unordered-list li
        {       
            background: red;        
            float:      left;
            height:     33%;
        }
    </style>    
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function()
        {
            function initializeUnorderedList(unorderedList)
            {
                // initialize layout
                var items = unorderedList.querySelectorAll("li");

                var blockIndices = [];              
                $(items).each(function(index, element)
                {
                    if ($(element).hasClass("block"))
                        blockIndices.push(index);
                });

                blockIndices.push(items.length);
                for (var i = 0, j = 0; i < blockIndices.length - 1; ++i)
                {
                    var width = 100 / (blockIndices[i + 1] - blockIndices[i]);
                    do {
                        $(items.item(j)).css("width", width + "%");
                    } while (++j < blockIndices[i + 1]);
                }
            }

            var unorderedLists = document.querySelectorAll(".unordered-list");
            for (var i = 0; i < unorderedLists.length; ++i)
                initializeUnorderedList(unorderedLists.item(i));
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <ul class="unordered-list">
        <li class="block">first row, first column</li>

        <li class="block">second row, first column</li>
        <li>second row, second column</li>

        <li class="block">third row, first column</li>
        <li>third row, second column</li>
        <li>third row, third column</li>
        <li>third row, fourth column</li>
        <li>third row, fifth column</li>
        <li>third row, sixth column</li>
        <li>third row, seventh column</li>
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Text inside the `<li>` elements should be centered (vertically and horizontally).

**EDIT:**
fixed bad markup

Comment: There should be no elements other than `li` within a `ul` or `ol`. The `div` elements wrapping the list make this invalid HTML mark-up.

Comment: @DavidThomas - +1 Thank you - fixed the bad markup.

Answer (score 0):

It appears centered in the following example:

**[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/RJzBQ/)**

Although it may not working depending on your browser and the validity of your mark-up, typically HTML doesn't like `<div>` elements within a `<ul>`.

**Proposed Solution:**

Using an indicator with which row you wanted to specify, such as '`1`','`2`', and '`3`' and let Javascript / jQuery handle your width situation.

**HTML:**

```
<ul class="unordered-list">
            <li class='1'>first row, first column</li>
            <li class='2'>second row, first column</li>
            <li class='2'>second row, second column</li>
            <li class='3'>third row, first column</li>
            <li class='3'>third row, second column</li>
            <li class='3'>third row, third column</li>
            <li class='3'>third row, fourth column</li>
            <li class='3'>third row, fifth column</li>
            <li class='3'>third row, sixth column</li>
            <li class='3'>third row, seventh column</li>
</ul>
```

**jQuery:**

```
//This will group each of your classes and apply the %-based width.
$('.1,.2,.3').each(function(){
    var width = Math.floor(100/($('.' + $(this).attr('class')).length));
    $(this).css('width',width + '%');
});
```

**[Prosposed Solution Example](http://jsfiddle.net/RJzBQ/3/)**

**jQuery (with attempted vertical-centering) :**

```
$('.1,.2,.3').each(function(){
    var width = Math.floor(100/($('.' + $(this).attr('class')).length));
    var height = $(this).height() / 2;
    $(this).css('width',width + '%')
    .css('margin-top',height + 'px')
    .css('height',($(this).height() - height) + 'px');
});
```

**[Try out the Vertical-Centered Example](http://jsfiddle.net/RJzBQ/6/)**

Comment: @ScottSimpson - Updated with a valid suggestion & valid mark-up.

Comment: +1 | Valid suggestion, but the actual problem is that the text is not centered vertically.

Comment: @Sascha, Ah, I'm sorry. I believe I misinterpreted the issue. I'll look into a fix for that.

Comment: @Sascha, Updated with an attempt at vertical-centering.